# How to transfer the contacts from one account to another account without duplicates

Tags: apex, account, contact

I want to transfer the contacts from account AA to account BB without duplicates.

If Account AA have **Dup2,Dup3,Dup4,Dup2,Dup3,Dup4,Dup2,Dup3 and Dup4** contacts, for the first time We need to transfer **Dup2,Dup3 and Dup4** to Account BB. If we run second time, it should not transfer duplicate records again and keeping them in same account AA.

```
Public class Example11 {
    Public List<Account> accs;
    Public List<Account> aacc;
    Public List<Contact> conupdate;
    Public Set<Contact> setUpdate;
    Public Set<String> setresult;
    Public List<Id> conids;

    Public void main(){
        setresult = new Set<String>();
        conIds = new List<Id>();
        setUpdate = new Set<Contact>();

        accs = [select id,name,(select id,lastname,AccountId from contacts) from Account where id='0012800001EcUSl'];
        for(Account aa : accs) {
            for(Contact cc: aa.contacts) {
                if(setresult.contains(cc.lastname)){
                    //conids.add(cc.id);
                }
                else{ 
                    conids.add(cc.id);
                    setresult.add(cc.lastname);
                }
            }
        }

        List<Contact> consd=[SELECT id,lastname,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id=: conids];
        aacc = [select id,name,(select id,lastname,AccountId from contacts) from Account where id='0012800001EcUSj'];
        for(Account aa : aacc) {
            for(Contact conc: aa.contacts) {
                for(Contact cca : consd) {
                    if(conc.lastname != cca.lastname){
                        cca.AccountId = '0012800001EcUSj';
                        setUpdate.add(cca);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        conUpdate = new List<Contact>(setUpdate);
        update conUpdate;
    }
}
```

I tried with above class. For the first time, i can able to send **Dup2,Dup3 and Dup4** to Account BB with out duplicates.

But the **first issue** is, while i am checking second time, duplicates contacts are saving to Account BB.

**Second issue** is, Contact records can able to transfer if account BB have atleast one contact. If account BB does not have any contacts, **Dup2,Dup3 and Dup4** are not transferring.

I tried with lot of efforts without success. But i couldn't succeed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the account id of contacts after checking in new contact list so change account id outside the for loop.

```
for(Account aa : aacc) {
   for(Contact conc: consd) {
       Boolean found = false;
       for(Contact cca : aa.contacts) {
           if(conc.lastname == cca.lastname){
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            conc.AccountId = 'your accountid' ;
            setUpdate.add(conc);
       }
   }
}
```

there are many nested loops so you can avoid them by using map. The above code works same as your code with solution to your problem.

```
Map<String,id> contMap = new Map<String,id>();
for(contact c:[select id,lastname,AccountId from Contact where AccountId = '0016F00001ya0sO']) {
    if(!contMap.containsKey(c.lastName)){
        contmap.put(c.lastname,c.id);
    } 
}

System.debug(contmap);

if(contmap.size() > 0) {
    Map<id,Contact> consd=new Map<id,Contact>([SELECT id,lastname,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id=: contMap.values()]);
    List<Account> aacc = [select id,name,(select id,lastname,AccountId from contacts) from Account where id='0016F00001wiKsL'];
    Account acc2 = new Account();
    acc2 = aacc.isEmpty() ? acc2 : aacc[0];
    if(acc2.id != null) {
        Map<String,Contact> newCont = new Map<String,Contact>();
        for(Contact c : acc2.contacts) {
            newCont.put(c.lastname, c);
        }

        System.debug(consd);

        List<Contact> setUpdate = new List<Contact>();

        for(String key: contMap.keySet()) {
            if(!newCont.containsKey(key)) {
                Id contId = contMap.get(key);
                System.debug(contId+' '+consd.get(contId));
                consd.get(contId).AccountId = acc2.id;
                setUpdate.add(consd.get(contId));
            }
        }
        update setUpdate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah blackPerl. This code some what working. I need to change this and let you inform tomorrow.

Comment: and if you observed i changed the order of looping

Comment: It did not work?

Comment: what is the issue? change the accpountids. those are my accountids.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56343/discussion-between-ks-kumaar-and-blackperl).